# Unable to solve TypeError message in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been searching around to check why was it that at line 7 there was a TypeError that says that my arguments are not converted during string formatting but to avail.

Is there anybody out here able to help me out and let me know what exactly went wrong with my codes so I am able to correct myself.

Below is the reference for my codes.

```
import sys

even, odd = [], []
count_odd, count_even = 0, 0

for value in sys.argv[1:]:
    if value % 2 == 0:    #TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
        even.append(value)
        total_even = sum(even)
        count_even += 1
    elif value % 2 == 1:
        odd.append(value)
        total_odd = sum(odd)
        count_odd += 1
    else:
        print "Please enter valid integers."

diff = max(sys.argv[1:]) - min(sys.argv[1:])

sys.argv[1:].remove(max(sys.argv[1:]))
sys.argv[1:].remove(min(sys.argv[1:]))
mean = sum(sys.argv[1:])/3

print .......
```

Comment: `if value % 2 == 0:` => `if int(value) % 2 == 0:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

command line arguments are of `str` type.

When using `%` on a string, you're invoking the formatting operator, and since your string doesn't contain any `%`, you get this weird message.

The fix is simple once you know that:

```
if int(value) % 2 == 0:
```

will do it

(the `please enter valid integers` part doesn't work, you have to catch the `ValueError` in case the argument isn't an integer instead)

Next strange errors you'll have is when you'll try to use `max` on the list of arguments. Wrong sorting will be used (lexicographical)

The best way would be to convert your arglist to integers beforehand, and process that list.

Let me propose a self-contained example which computes odd & even list and diff, using more pythonic techniques (and also more performant, ex: no need to compute the sum of your numbers at each iteration):

```
import sys

even, odd = [], []

argument_list = ["1","10","24","15","16"]  # sys.argv[1:]

integer_list = [int(x) for x in argument_list]  # let python signal the conversion errors and exit

for value in integer_list:
    # ternary to select which list to append to
    (odd if value % 2 else even).append(value)

total_even = sum(even)
total_odd = sum(odd)
count_even = len(even)  # if you need that
count_odd = len(odd)

diff = max(integer_list) - min(integer_list)
```

Comment: I tried adding that but after I typed in a few numbers, it gave me this error. 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12,'

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv is automatically a list of strings.  Typecast it using

```
int(value)
```

when using it to use it as an integer.